# In C: How to read input from a file when there are both strings and integers?

Tags: c, function, io

In this program I would like to take information from an input file like this:

```
1 Tokyo
2 Ueno
3 Ikebukuro
4 Shibuya
5 Shinjuku
6 Akihabara
```

I want to have one function read the file, another function to find a station number based on a string the user enters and another to find the station name based on a number the user enters. The following are the functions that I need to use:

```
void read_file_stations(FILE *file, char stations[][MAX_STATION_LENGTH]);
int find_station_number(int num_stations, char stations[][MAX_STATION_LENGTH], char search_str[MAX_STATION_LENGTH]);
void find_station_name(char stations[][MAX_STATION_LENGTH], int station_num, char station_name[MAX_STATION_LENGTH]);
```

I'm not sure how to go about parsing the data once I read it from the file. I can use the stdio, stdlib, string, and stdbool libraries for this problem. Some ideas to push me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possibility 1: read lines from file with `fgets`, parse with `sscanf`.  Possibility 2: read (number, name) pairs from file with `fscanf`.  Is it possible for the names to contain spaces?  (like `7 New York`)

Comment: All possible names with spaces will have _ between them

Comment: Possibility 3: read lines from file with `fgets`, extract number with `strtol`, `strtol` returns pointer to rest of line, which is name.

Comment: If the names contain `_` instead of spaces, that makes things considerably easier, because you can use a simple `%s` with any of the `scanf` family.  (With that said, the `scanf` family has plenty of other shortcomings.)